# using data from config.php in phpunit class

Tags: php, phpunit

i am trying to write some tests in which i am using data from `config.php` file. the files are in the same folder.
i know i can't include files from inside a class but i also don't know what is the correct way to use this delicate data in my phpunit test class.

the class looks like this:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../../src/vendor/autoload.php';
$config = require "config.php";

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

echo $config['base_url']; //HERE I GET THE DATA

class ApiAdTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{--

    public function testApiAd_postAd()
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => --DATA FROM CONFIG.PHP--]);
        $response = $client->post(--DATA FROM CONFIG.PHP--, ['form_params' => [
          'name' => 'bellow content - guzzle testing',
          'description' => 'guzzle testing ad - demo'
          ]]);
        $code = $response->getStatusCode();
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $adId = $data->id;

        $this->assertEquals($code, 200);


        return $adId;
    }
```

what will be te correct way to use this data from config.php in my testing class??

**UPDATE**:
config.php content:

```
<?php

return array(
    'base_url' => 'http://10.0.0.0/',
    'path' => 'api/ad/',
);
```

Comment: can you post an example of config.php?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand: you want to make different test with different version of config.php?

Comment: nope, same config file all over.

Comment: so why not simply do `new Client(['base_uri' =>$config['base_url'] ] );`?

Comment: because i get this error: `1) ApiRuleTest::testApiRule_postRule
Undefined variable: config
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the config.php file in the setup method of the testcase and assign the value to a class attribute, then you can use in the test method as follow:

```
<?php

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../../src/vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;


class ApiAdTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $config;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->config = require("config.php");

    }


    public function testApiAd_postAd()
    {
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' =>$this->config['base_url'] ] );
        $response = $client->post($this->config['path'], ['form_params' => [
          'name' => 'bellow content - guzzle testing',
          'description' => 'guzzle testing ad - demo'
          ]]);
        $code = $response->getStatusCode();
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $adId = $data->id;

        $this->assertEquals($code, 200);


        return $adId;
    }

}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you're using composer, a package I like to use for setting configuration is called [PHP Dotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv).

It uses a `.env` file in the root of your project and allows you to add your own settings to PHP's `$_ENV` array. You can then pull these out by using `getenv()` wherever you wish to use them.

You can then add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file so that you don't accidentally commit it to source control.

Comment: thx but i am looking for more of a 'native' php solution where i dont need to install any other packages

Comment: I'll make another answer for a native solution

Comment: See my other answer for a native solution (assuming you use composer)

Answer (score 0):

As a native PHP solution, I suggest using composer's autoloader to load an extra configuration file. For this you can define a `files` array in your `composer.json` file like so:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["config.php"]
    }
}
```

Then in your configuration file, I would create a global function to access configuration variables:

```
<?php

function config($item) {
    $config = [
        // Config variables here
    ];

    return $config[$item];
}
```

After running `composer dumpautoload`, you can then access `config()` globally in your application to grab configuration items.

(You may want to adapt this solution for your requirements, I prefer using my previous answer)

*Note: If you're using source control, do not commit your config.php file as this is a security risk*

Comment: nice solution but for the structure of my program the bottom solution works better